# How to customize module selection page?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

**Odoo 14 Community Edition**

Here I captured the module selection page from Odoo demo that I searched from the web. (the version is different but shouldn't matter).

[image: module selection page]

I am looking for a way to customize this particular page. I don't know the term to call this page officially.

I will customize it via creating a customized module for it.

Which files should I inherit to modify the page? and how?

Comment: What do you mean by "customizing"? Changing the order of main menus or some other things?

Comment: @CZoellner Yes. Changing order of the menus, changing the UI maybe via HTML/XML and CSS by Xpath, and maybe adding some extra sections (divs) here and there into the page.

Comment: You see `ir.ui.menu` in the main menu. So just change there `sequence` field to change order.